# Is there any workaround solution for show month view in clarity UI date picker

Tags: vmware-clarity

How to show months only in date picker, i am looking for this long time but they are not implemented at, so is any work around solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Format **property.**

```
   var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM" 'or whatever you want
```

Comment: what is this dateTimePicker1 ? and how i use this in view can you provide sample example

Comment: var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"